# Calling ffmpeg from Java calling command line/ shell script throws "Trailing garbage after a filter" Error

Tags: java, ffmpeg, command-line

Calling ffmpeg from Java throws `"Trailing garbage after a filter"` Error

I tried to call from Java application command string over dockerized ffmpeg, same result.

```
docker run --rm  -v sample-test:/config linuxserver/ffmpeg  -loop 1 -t 5 -i  config/1.jpeg  -loop 1 -t 5 -i  config/3.jpeg  -y -filter_complex "[0:v]fade=t=out:st=4:d=1[v0];  [1:v]fade=t=in:st=0:d=1,fade=t=out:st=4:d=1[v1];  [v0][v1]concat=n=2:v=1:a=0,format=yuv420p[v];" -map "[v]"  config/output/video_java.mp4
```

My goal is to run such a query from Java application

```
ffmpeg \
-loop 1 -t 5 -i input0.png \
-loop 1 -t 5 -i input1.png \
-loop 1 -t 5 -i input2.png \
-loop 1 -t 5 -i input3.png \
-loop 1 -t 5 -i input4.png \
-filter_complex \
"[0:v]scale=1280:720:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=1280:720:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2,setsar=1,fade=t=out:st=4:d=1[v0]; \
 [1:v]scale=1280:720:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=1280:720:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2,setsar=1,fade=t=in:st=0:d=1,fade=t=out:st=4:d=1[v1]; \
 [2:v]scale=1280:720:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=1280:720:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2,setsar=1,fade=t=in:st=0:d=1,fade=t=out:st=4:d=1[v2]; \
 [3:v]scale=1280:720:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=1280:720:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2,setsar=1,fade=t=in:st=0:d=1,fade=t=out:st=4:d=1[v3]; \
 [4:v]scale=1280:720:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=1280:720:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2,setsar=1,fade=t=in:st=0:d=1,fade=t=out:st=4:d=1[v4]; \
 [v0][v1][v2][v3][v4]concat=n=5:v=1:a=0,format=yuv420p[v]" -map "[v]" out.mp4


Runtime.getRuntime().exec(String.format("/bin/sh -c " + ffmpegCommand));
```

Why it happens and how to solve? Appreciating

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put that complex command in a script and do the following. Works for me:

```
import java.io.*;

public class Animator {
    private static final String[] COMMAND = {
        "/bin/bash",
        "mkvid.sh"
    };
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Process p = new ProcessBuilder(COMMAND).redirectError(new File("ffmpeg.err.log")).redirectOutput(new File("ffmpeg.out.log")).start();
        int exitVal = p.waitFor();
        System.exit(exitVal);
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot, i asked after 1 day trouble. you saved the next day ^_^